# Can I designated the combination of fields to be unique in an Entity bean?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

Is it possible to annotate two or more fields in an entity bean so that the combination of them is unique? For example:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    private String field1; 
    private String field2;
    //<Getter and setters etc>
}
```

in `MyEntity` I would like to make it legitimate to have `field1` data duplicated across all MyEntity classes and similarly for `field2`, however the combination for `field1` and `field2` should be unique across all `MyEntity` objects. Can I do this with annotations and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. I think this is what you need.

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"field1", "field2"})
```